# find index of div that has specific class name

Tags: jquery

How can I find div's index that has specific class name using each?
here is html:

```
<div class="">text1</div>
<div class="">text2</div>
<div class="active">text3</div>
<div class="">text4</div>
<div class="">text5</div>
<div class="">text6</div>
```

So basicly i needto find class name and then find his div index number? any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need each for that just do this:

```
$("div.active").index();
```

Here, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/SKBvW/

Keep in mind that the returned index is zero based, thus the code will return 2 for the posted HTML, because it's the third div.

Comment: @Vega part 2. Coz 'active' is the only div named

Comment: Thank ye fer th'advice! Arrr!

Comment: @Vega index() will work as expected, check the fiddle. active is the name of the class OP is trying to find

Comment: caveat: it is the index number _at that level_.  So nested `div`s reset to index=0

Comment: @mcalex Indeed. Nice addition. In OP's scenario, I think that will not be an issue, but it's important to keep this in mind